# Why is there a switch inside the incinerator?

Tags: plot-explanation, gattaca

In **Gattaca**, at the end of the movie when Jerome commits suicide, why is there a switch inside the incinerator for him to turn on? In the beginning, when Vincent is finished getting rid of his genetic material he turns it on from the outside, but why is there one on the inside? Did Jerome plan this all along or...?

Answer (score 10):

Look closely at the scene:

It seems to me that the switch is not inside, but accessible through the grid. Also, when we see him enter the incinerator, there is no switch visible on that side.